# Find columns with multiple unique values per group when grouping by other variables in R

Tags: r, group-by, datatable, grouping, categorical-data

For example, I have a dataset (my real dataset has hundreds of columns and millions of observations):

```
> data
    time_period country      var1   var2 var3
 1:     2000_Q2     USA     april spring  ABS
 2:     2000_Q2     USA       may spring  CND
 3:     2000_Q3     USA      june summer  ABS
 4:     2005_Q2   Italy     april spring  ABS
 5:     2010_Q2   Italy       may spring  ABS
 6:     2010_Q2   Italy       may spring  ABS
 7:     2012_Q2   Italy       may spring  ABS
 8:     2018_Q4   China   october autumn  ABS
 9:     2018_Q4   China september autumn  ARF
10:     2018_Q4   China   october autumn  ABS
11:     2018_Q4   China   october autumn  ABS
12:     2000_Q2     USA     march spring  ABS
```

I need to group the `data` by `time_period` and `country` and find all variables that will have more than 1 unique value per group (at least for one group). In my dataset, all these variables are categorical with type chr.

I did this in the following way:

```
colnames_to_group = c("time_period", "country", "var1", "var2", "var3")
data_count = data[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN), 
                  by = c("time_period", "country"), 
                  .SDcols = colnames_to_group]
> data_count
   time_period country time_period country var1 var2 var3
1:     2000_Q2     USA           1       1    3    1    2
2:     2000_Q3     USA           1       1    1    1    1
3:     2005_Q2   Italy           1       1    1    1    1
4:     2010_Q2   Italy           1       1    1    1    1
5:     2012_Q2   Italy           1       1    1    1    1
6:     2018_Q4   China           1       1    2    1    2

tokeep <- which(sapply(data_count, is.numeric))
multiple_values <- sapply(data_count[ , tokeep, with = FALSE], function(x) any(x > 1))

> multiple_values
time_period     country        var1        var2        var3 
      FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE 

colnames_with_multiple_values <<- names(multiple_values[(multiple_values == TRUE)]) 

> colnames_with_multiple_values
[1] "var1" "var3"
```

**This works and this is what I want to get. But for huge datasets, this works for a very long time.**

Are there any ways to implement this more optimally?

Thanks for the any help!

Comment: Can you specify which step is taking more time.  It is the group by `uniqueN`

Comment: [`uniqueN()` is very slow compared to `length(unique())`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3739)

Comment: @akrun, most of the time is spent creating a table `data_count` with function `uniqueN()`

Comment: I found that for my case, the `n_distinct` function works much faster.

Answer (score 1):

For very large vectors, `uniqueN()` is faster. 

But when there're many subgroups as in my task and `uniqueN()` is supposed to be called millions of times, the performance's slowing down is significant. 

In this case, it is better to use the `n_distinct` function from `dplyr`.

```
Unit: seconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 data_table 16.692984 16.692984 16.692984 16.692984 16.692984 16.692984     1
      dplyr  3.506646  3.506646  3.506646  3.506646  3.506646  3.506646     1
```